# Segmentation_Fault error when reading from a file.cfg

Tags: c, ubuntu, segmentation-fault, config

Hi i'm trying to write a code  how can print a dynamic struct  which values are taken from a config file
this is the config file containing the number of gateway and for each one we have different parameters

```
nbre_GW = "3" 
GW1 = "192.168.1.12;502;1;2;3"
GW2 = "192.168.1.13;505;5;6;45"
GW3 ="192.168.1.14;503;11;12;3"
```

i'm using this structure :

```
typedef struct {
    char  IP[12] ;
    int port;
    int slave [50] ;
} GW_t ;
```

while executing the code I've got the error segmentation fault
This the function read config

```
int readConfig(int gw_nbr)
{
    char tmpBuff[8];
    char chaine [50] ; 
    config_t cfg;
    const char * l_nbre = NULL;
    const char * l_chaine = NULL;
    
    
    config_init(&cfg);
    printf("hello");
    //printf("\r\n========================== READING FROM CONFIG FILE ==========================\r\n");
    
    if (!config_read_file(&cfg, CONFIG_FILENAME)) {
        
        fprintf(stdout, "Configuration file not found!");
        config_destroy(&cfg);
        return -1;
    }

  printf ("read config file");
    if (!config_lookup_string(&cfg, "nbre_GW", &l_nbre)) {
        fprintf(stdout, "No 'nbre_GW' setting in configuration file.\r\n");
        config_destroy(&cfg);
        return -1;
    }
  
   gw_nbr = atoi(l_nbre);
   
    gwArray = (GW_t *) malloc (gw_nbr* sizeof(GW_t)) ;

    for (int i =1 ; i<= gw_nbr ; i++)
    {
        sprintf(tmpBuff,"GW%d",i);
        if (!config_lookup_string(&cfg, tmpBuff, &l_chaine)) {
            fprintf(stdout, "No 'GW' setting in configuration file.\r\n");
            config_destroy(&cfg);
            return -1;
        }
        
        strcpy(chaine, l_chaine);
        
        int len = strlen(chaine);
        
        char d[] = ";";
        printf ("first strtok");
        char *p = strtok(chaine, d);
        
        strcpy(gwArray[i].IP,p);
        
        p = strtok(NULL, d);
        gwArray[i].port = atoi(p);
        int j =0 ;
        while(p != NULL)
        {
            p = strtok(NULL, d);
            gwArray[i].slave[j] = atoi(p);
            j++ ;
        }

    }

 }
```

Comment: `char  IP[12] ;` is too small anyway.

Comment: In addition to @wildplasser comment, consider that C-strings also stores '\0' character, so you actually need char IP[13] symbols for your example. Considering corner-cases for ip addresses like "255.255.255.255" you are required 16 chars to store it.

Comment: `for (int i =1 ; i<= gw_nbr ; i++)` <<-- array-indexing starts at zero in C. (so 'GW1' will be located in `gwArray[0]` )

Comment: What is `config_lookup_string`? Can you link to the repo so that we can download and try running the code? Have you tried running it in a debugger, or with Address Sanitizer?

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong with this code:

1. You allocate three items (because `nbre_GW` is 3) in `gwArray`.
2. You leave `gwArray[0]` untouched, containing garbage (`calloc` zeroes memory, but `malloc` doesn't).
3. You write to `gwArray[3]`, which was never allocated.
4. The function returns -1 for errors, but garbage for success.

So the program could crash when it tries to interpret the garbage in `gwArray[0]`, or when whatever was overwritten by `gwArray[3]` is read, or when it tries to process a garbage number of gateways. Without running the whole program in a debugger, there's no way to tell, but it's pretty likely one of these causes.